# How to allow ordering of is_in_stock = 0 products?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.8, inventory

I'm using a popular dropship module that uses the Magento inventory as the local inventory and when an item is not available locally (`is_in_stock = 0`) items get assigned to various vendors. So the `is_in_stock = 0` status needs to be preserved and not just overwritten to return true.

**What should be changed in Magento so that `is_in_stock = 0` can be purchased?**

By Default - if you try to add an item  with (`is_in_stock = 0`) to your cart, Magento will stop you with this message: `This product is currently out of stock.`

I found the 2 files that trigger that message.

```
app\code\local\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item\Item.php
app\code\local\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php
```

By modifying the `observer.php`, I'm able to successfully add an `is_in_stock = 0` item to the cart and check out but I'm not sure this is the best way. I also noticed when viewing the order in the admin area, the item details don't show up but the item totals do.

I just added one line of code to the `observer.php` that skipped the step which checked for `if (!$stockItem->getIsInStock()`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit too simplistic but have you tried to change the setting `System > Configuration > Inventory > Backorders > Allow Qty Below 0`?

Comment: There's 2 combinations: [Allow Backorders + is_in_stock = true](**This works**, but this isn't my problem) & [Allow Backorders + is_in_stock = false(**Doesn't work**, this is my problem)